# Fetch request is being being blocked by CORS policy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api

I'm making an API request to the [Beehiiv API](https://www.beehiiv.com/developers/docs), to get my list of publications.

Inside my React component, I've set up a fetch request to the API. However the request is being being blocked by the CORS policy. Request code below:

```
async function makeRequest(){
 const fetchOptions = {

        method: 'get',
      
        headers: {
          "X-ApiKey": '<MY API KEY>',
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : '*'
        },
        
 }
 fetch('https://api.beehiiv.com/v1/publications', fetchOptions).then( response => response.json() )
       .then( data => console.log(data) )
}

makeRequest();
```

The response in the console is as follows:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.beehiiv.com/v1/publications' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Calling other API's does not seem to result in getting blocked.

Any ideas on why this may be happening? Please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like if you want to send requests from localhost:3000 you will need beehiiv api to enable that origin. or use the no-cors mode instead

Comment: The API simply doesn't support cross-origin requests (also, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header, not a request header).

Comment: @ColinHale There isn't an option on the Beehiiv side to enable a custom origin unfortunately. I also tried no-cors mode, however it results in me getting a 401 error

Comment: @robertklep so the API won't allow external requests? What would the point of the API be then? Sorry just looking for clarity

Comment: You need to proxy the request. Maybe try [https://corsproxy.github.io/](https://corsproxy.github.io/).

Comment: @simplon78 sure it supports external requests, just not made from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

From [beehiiv API documentation](https://www.beehiiv.com/developers/docs):

> API keys are considered sensitive data and should not be shared with anyone. Be careful not to expose the API key in your source code or any other public location (including front-end code).

The API isn't supposed to be called from the frontend.

You need to make AJAX requests to your own server, which then calls the API, so the API key isn't exposed.

Comment: Ahhh thank you for pointing this out! I just started in creating React websites and am still learning. So when you say make the call to the server, I'm using Vercel, would Vercel make the API call? If you could point me to a resource that details how to "make AJAX requests to your own server" that would really help. Everything I can find seems to be front end. Thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Vercel.

Comment: any thoughts on a PHP solution?